# Cakephp 2.x Stuck with Auth component with different models

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I'm coding a app for car selling, i'm stucked with auth component.
I have 3 kind of access:

```
admin: app owner
dealers: the owners of car dealers
user: people who whach car offers and make questions etc
```

i'm not working with roles, ech one (admin, dealer and users) has an username and password from diferent models, so i'm very lost.

i'm not asking for codes, i just wanna a good explanation about how can i deal with auth assuming this scenario.

Comment: What are your ideas so far?  What have you found when searching for this? ...etc

Comment: i understand how auth works.. but i dont know what controller i have to call auth, i dont understant how tell to auth what Model i'm using (they always look for users table) etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's just a matter of allowing/denying access for a certain user. If you can recognize the users model in controllers beforeFilter method, you can allow/deny access accordingly with `$this->Auth->allow()` or `$this->Auth->deny()` (in beforeFilter method). So maybe you can put some pseudo-role in the session after the login if you don't wish to have it in the db table. You can then put Auths allow/deny in conditions on the pseudo-role stored in Session.

Or have I misunderstood the question?

**UPDATE**

I just realized that you are probably refering to actual login. Changing the default Model is documented in [CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers). See `userModel` configuration key. Keep in mind that you are supposed to change this in beforeFilter method.

Comment: but like i said. i dont have a table called users and each user with one role. i have 3 tables for each type of user. like i said too auth component always point to User model..

Comment: See the answer update for the auth always pointing to User model.